# Classic Cryptic Cluing

Tags: riddle, cryptic-crosswords, poetry, music

> (Guiltless in cent.) when I've taken a chair.
>   (Absence of all thing) asserting thing there.
>   (Not any human one) it is true.
>   (Sure of kw.) a small charge for you.

The answer is a song title. "Classic" refers to the song not, of course, this riddle. The song is one of the best known I could think of. Most of the clues are not cryptic (in the cryptic crossword sense) yet the cryptic mindset is important to arrive at the solution.

There are no intentional acrostics here. I just noticed that the first letters spell "snag" backwards. This has nothing to do with the solution.

Hint:

> Perhaps to get it, you should proceed piece-wise and Chinese fashion.

Hint:

> Change your perspective. Think vertically. I have a feeling the answer and its opposite will come to you suddenly.

Comment: What is "kw."? Some German thing?

Comment: @question_asker No German in this puzzle. I should use Romansh sometime and really mess people up. Of course I'd have to learn some Romansh first.

Comment: I'd be thrilled if people did more multilingual puzzles!

Comment: This is a tough one, Mr. M. I hate to ask you for a hint*, but I'd love a hint if you feel like it.  * This may not actually be true

Comment: @question_asker Frequently it means kilowatt.  In the case of charge, I'd wager that it definitely does -- I just don't know why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is

> (I Can't Get No) Satisfaction by the Rolling Stones

General Reasoning

> The clues in brackets refer to the part of the title in brackets and the clues not in brackets to the Satisfaction bit

(Guiltless in cent.)

> 'Guiltless' is a synonym for 'innocent' and 'in cent' is 'innocent' without 'no'

(Absence of all thing)

> 'Absence of all' could be a synonym for 'nothing' and 'thing' is 'nothing' without 'no'

(Not any human one)

> 'Not any human' is 'no-one' and 'one' is 'no-one' without 'no'.

(Sure of kw.)

> 'Sure of' is synonymous with 'know' and 'kw' is 'know' without 'no'

Basically

> For all the clues in brackets, I Can't Get 'No'

For the rest,
when I've taken a chair.

> Sat

asserting thing there.

> Is

it is true.

> Fact

a small charge for you.

> Ion

Comment: Bravo! I had vaguely figured on some sort of "no" with a couple of them but didn't figure out the mechanic. Also thought the same with "small charge".  I just can't do anything that complex! :P

Comment: Congratulations! I hope the answer was satisfying.

Comment: Yes, very satisfying. Great puzzle, by the way. Lots of clever misdirection, I think I needed the hints.